# Emacs transparent after fresh install

Tags: debugging, start-up, gtk3

Complete emacs beginner here. Just installed emacs in my Manjaro (awesomewm edition) machine using pacman.

The emacs window is almost completely transparent, I can't read anything. If started from a terminal, it raises these errors:

```sh
(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_concrete_size: assertion 'default_width > 0' failed

(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_surface: assertion 'surface_width > 0' failed

(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_concrete_size: assertion 'default_width > 0' failed

(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_surface: assertion 'surface_width > 0' failed

(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_concrete_size: assertion 'default_width > 0' failed

(emacs:4193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:20:57.211: _gtk_css_image_get_surface: assertion 'surface_width > 0' failed
```

Any clues on what's wrong?

Screenshot:
[image]

Note: also tried installing emacs with another package manager (guix) as a foreign package manager. Still got the same problem.

Comment: Are you starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If you do that, do you see the same problem? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Those messages are GTK complaining about your theme, and may or may not be related to your problem. If they are related, perhaps trying a different theme would give you better results.

Comment: @Drew The problem vanishes if I run `emacs -Q`. I'll try and debug the init file then.
Note: I still get an error `(emacs:3317): Gtk-CRITICAL` though.

Comment: @Drew For some reason the .emacs, .emacs.el or init.el files are nowhere to be found. So it seems emacs is running with the defaults? But then it shouldn't have a theme, I guess...

Comment: `emacs -Q` doesn't load either your init file or the `site-lisp.el` file. `emacs -q` (lowercase)  doesn't load your init file but still loads `site-lisp.el`. So maybe check both, and if you see a difference check what's in library `site-lisp.el`.

Comment: Um... I thought Awesome was a tiling DM... what would "transparent" look in this situation? (I don't use Awesome, I use StumpWM, but it's the same idea). Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Drew I'm starting to think there's a problem with the emacs installation using pacman: there is no `site-lisp.el` or init file anywhere to be found...

Comment: @wvxvw Added a screenshot of the emacs windows. As you can see, it is almost completely transparent (you mostly see my wallpaper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Soap!

This seems unrelated to Emacs.  I guess it could be related to your window manager (AwesomeWM), some kind of X11 compositor like Compton or the configuration files associated with those.

Try to add the following to your `init.el`.

`(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 100))`

Comment: Killing compton did solve the issue, but I'd still like a permanent solution. It is still strange that compton only has issues with emacs though.

Comment: Try to add the following to your `init.el`: `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 100))`

Comment: I do not have a init.el file. Shall I create one in .emacs.d/?

Comment: Yes, just create it at `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: Working flawlessly now :D